# Spring boot NumberFormatExeption при repository.findAll()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

#### Всякий раз когда я пытаюсь вызвать `myRepo.findAll()` вылетает ошибка

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "courier"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549) ~[na:na]
```

---

#### Такое получается только с одним из репозиториев:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ua.com.anly.entity.Order;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepo extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {
    Order findById(int id);
}
```

---

#### Entity

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_product",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "order_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }
    )
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    private int orderNumber;

    private int price;

    private int status;

    private int deliveryType;

    private int payType;

    private String address;

    private int postOfficeId;

    public Order() {
    }

    public long getCountOfProduct(int productId) {
        List ids = products.stream().map(Product::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ids.stream().filter(Integer.valueOf(productId)::equals).count();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getDeliveryType() {
        return deliveryType;
    }

    public void setDeliveryType(int deliveryType) {
        this.deliveryType = deliveryType;
    }

    public int getPayType() {
        return payType;
    }

    public void setPayType(int payType) {
        this.payType = payType;
    }

    public int getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(int orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getPostOfficeId() {
        return postOfficeId;
    }

    public void setPostOfficeId(int postOfficeId) {
        this.postOfficeId = postOfficeId;
    }
}
```

---

Мистика в том что `NumberFormatExeption` всегда для строки courier.

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "courier"`

---

#### Единственный метод в программе который использует `courier`

В последствии я его закоментировал, ничем не помогло. Программа по прежнему пытается привести строку "courier" к `Double`

В принципе его разбирать наверное нету смысла, он довольно 'грязный', к тому-же он закомментирован.

```
@PostMapping("/order")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String createOrder(
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String courier,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String postOffice,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String cashless,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String onDelivery,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String cod,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String address,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) Integer postOfficeId,
                              @RequestParam(name = "productId", required = false) Integer[] ids,
                              @RequestParam(name = "productSize", required = false) Integer[] sizes,
                              @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                              Model model) {
        int orderNum = getUniqueOrderNumber(10000, 99999); // там использую .findAll() и получаю ошибку

        Order order = new Order();

        order.setUser(user);
        order.setStatus(1);

        order.setOrderNumber(orderNum);

        if (courier != null) {
            order.setDeliveryType(1);

            if (address != null) order.setAddress(address);
            else order.setAddress("Адресс не указан");

            if (cashless != null) order.setPayType(1);
            else if (onDelivery != null) order.setPayType(2);
        } else if (postOffice != null) {
            order.setDeliveryType(1);

            order.setPostOfficeId(postOfficeId);

            if (cashless != null) order.setPayType(1);
            else if (cod != null) order.setPayType(3);
        }

        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        int price = 0;

        for (Product product : user.getUniqueCard()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                if (product.getId() == ids[i]) {
                    price += product.getPrice() * sizes[i];

                    for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++) {
                        products.add(product);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        order.setProducts(products);
        order.setPrice(price);

        orderRepo.save(order);

        userService.removeAllFromCard(user);
        userService.addOrder(user, order);

        try {
            String subject = "Order created";
            String message = String.format(
                    "Order %s created", orderNum
            );

            mailSender.send(user.getEmail(), subject, message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Не удалось отправить письмо на почту. Номер заказа: " + orderNum);
            return mainController.main(model);
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    private int getUniqueOrderNumber(int min, int max) {
        Iterable<Order> orders = orderRepo.findAll(); //тут получаю ошибку

        int num = 10000;
        boolean isUnique = false;
        while (!isUnique) {
            isUnique = true;

            num = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

            for(Order order : orders) {
                if (order.getOrderNumber() == num) {
                    isUnique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return num;
    }
```

---

#### Stack trace

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "courier"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.getDouble(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:238) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractNumericValueFactory.createFromBytes(AbstractNumericValueFactory.java:57) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeByteArray(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:133) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1285) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:786) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:807) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1866) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1794) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1615) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at ua.com.anly.controller.MainController.adminPage(MainController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
        at ua.com.anly.controller.MainController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eac7b922.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at ua.com.anly.controller.MainController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f8773134.adminPage(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:152) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
...
```

Comment: Также есть приватный репозиторий на гитхабе, если нужно могу добавить

Comment: Я думаю что спринг где-то, что-то неправильно сохранил и теперь портит мне жизнь)

Comment: проверьте базу, может быть у вас до этого в колонке была строка, а теперь вы поменяли на int\double, а в базе осталась колонка со старым значением, вот он и не понимает, что делать, он вроде сначала пытается int вытащить, затем у него не получается и он мучается

Comment: @Komdosh ... И правда, в миграциях были несходства. Аж стыдно)